# How do I create a Function object using a compiled Code object?

Tags: python, function

So I have the following code.

```
code_string = """def f1(p1, p2, p3):
    print("a{}, b{}, c{}".format(p1, p2, p3))
def f2():
    print("text")
"""

code = compile(code_string, '<string>', 'exec')

f1 = code.co_consts[0]
f2 = code.co_consts[2]  # code.co_consts is the name of the prior function ("f1")
```

It compiles a string with some functions into a code object and then stores the code objects of the functions to separate variables.

**What I want to know is how to create function objects using the code objects above so I can just call them.**

So say `ff1 = new_function(f1)` where `isinstance(ff1, types.FunctionType)` would be `True` and I could just do `ff1('a', 'b', 'c')` to print `"aa, bb, cc"`.

The code objects in `f1` and `f2` can be executed using exec. (Though I don't know how to pass arguments into `f1` or make a bound method out of them this way)

Answer (score 1):

All `compile()` does is translate the Python source code (think contents of `*.py` files) into a compiled version (think `*.pyc` files).  The source code must be syntactically correct, but need not be valid.  In the case of your `code_string`, this means it has compiled the two `def <name>: <body>` statements into a binary form, but it has not executed those `def` statements to actually create the functions.

You need to execute the compiled `code` object in order to actually *execute* the `def` statement that creating the functions.

However, as [norok2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5218354/norok2) mentions, simply executing code in arbitrary strings is a security risk.  It can be done somewhat safer by controlling the environment the code is executed in.  We can create an environment where the only function that exists is the `print` function:

```
code_string = """\
def f1(p1, p2, p3):
    print("a{}, b{}, c{}".format(p1, p2, p3))
def f2():
    print("text")
"""

code = compile(code_string, '<string>', 'exec')

builtins = {
    'print': print,
    }

code_globals = {'__builtins__': builtins}
exec(code, code_globals)

f1 = code_globals['f1']
f_two = code_globals['f2']

f1(1, 2, 3)
f_two()
```

Now it is much more difficult for the code to break out of the sandbox.  For example, if you add `import sys` inside the `code_string`, you'll get an `NameError: name '__import__' is not defined.`, and so on.

By careful construction of the available `builtins`, you can allow as much functionality as needed.

Of course, since we are no longer using the caller's global context to create the definitions, you need to extract the created functions out of the `code_globals` dictionary, as demonstrated above.

---

#### Why compile?

You generally use `compile()` when you want to execute the resulting code multiple times.  That's not the case here.  You will likely be executing the code exactly once to *create* the `f1` and `f2` functions.  (Once created, they can be called many times, but they only need to be created once.)  Therefore, we should use `exec()` instead of `compile()`, so we don't get (and accidentally keep) a reference to the intermediate code object:

```
code_string = """\
def f1(p1, p2, p3):
    print("a{}, b{}, c{}".format(p1, p2, p3))
def f2():
    print("text")
"""

builtins = {
    'print': print,
    }

code_globals = {'__builtins__': builtins}
exec(code_string, code_globals)

f1 = code_globals['f1']
f_two = code_globals['f2']

f1(1, 2, 3)
f_two()
```

---

## Why code.co_consts is fragile

[S.B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13944524/s-b) shows how you can directly create functions from `code.co_consts[...]`, and indirectly demonstrates how fragile this is.

Consider the OP's code:

```
f2 = code.co_consts[2]
```

compared with S.B's:

```
f2_code_object = code.co_consts[1]
```

Apparently, something changed (Python version?  An edit to the `code_string`?) and `f2` moved from index 2 to index 1.  There is no obvious mapping from the indices in `co_consts` to the expected function names.

To drive this home, consider this more complex example, which highlights the differences between compiling the Python script and executing it:

```
from types import FunctionType

code_string = """\
if True == False:
    print("Defining f1...")
    def f1(p1, p2, p3):
        print("a{}, b{}, c{}".format(p1, p2, p3))
else:
    print("Defining alternate f1")
    def f1(p1, p2, p3):
        print("c{}, b{}, a{}".format(p3, p2, p1))
"""

builtins = {
    'print': print,
    }
code_globals = {'__builtins__': builtins}

print("Using compile() and code.co_consts")
code = compile(code_string, '<string>', 'exec')

for idx, item in enumerate(code.co_consts):
    print(f"  .co_consts[{idx}] = {item!r}")

f1 = FunctionType(code.co_consts[3], code_globals) # How do we know it is 3???
f1(1, 2, 3)

print()
print("Using exec():")
code_globals = {'__builtins__': builtins}
exec(code_string, code_globals)

f1 = code_globals['f1']
f1(1, 2, 3)
```

Now `code_string` will conditionally define the function `f1` based on the execution of the code.

Output:

```
Using compile() and code.co_consts
  .co_consts[0] = True
  .co_consts[1] = False
  .co_consts[2] = 'Defining f1...'
  .co_consts[3] = <code object f1 at 0x000001A3B567FA30, file "<string>", line 3>
  .co_consts[4] = 'Defining alternate f1'
  .co_consts[5] = <code object f1 at 0x000001A3B56C8330, file "<string>", line 7>
  .co_consts[6] = None
a1, b2, c3

Using exec():
Defining alternate f1
c3, b2, a1
```

Note that:

- `compile()`

  - created two different `code object f1` entities,
  - does not execute either `print()` statement.
- `exec()`

  - actually evaluates the condition in the `if` statement,
  - executes the `print()` statement in one code path,
  - defines the function `"f1"` from that code path only.

Answer (score 1):

You already extracted the code objects, now all you have to do is to create the functions objects using `types.FuncitonType`. It accepts:

1. Code object
2. Reference to the global module
3. Name

```py
from types import FunctionType

code_string = """\
def f1(p1, p2, p3):
    print("a{}, b{}, c{}".format(p1, p2, p3))
def f2():
    print("text")
"""

code = compile(code_string, "<string>", "exec")

f1_code_object = code.co_consts[0]
f2_code_object = code.co_consts[1]

f1 = FunctionType(f1_code_object, globals(), "f1")
f2 = FunctionType(f2_code_object, globals(), "f2")
print(f1)
print(f2)
f1(10, 20, 30)
f2()
```

output:

```
<function f1 at 0x1042a2980>
<function f2 at 0x1042a2a20>
a10, b20, c30
text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just execute the code with `exec(code)` and `f1` and `f2` will be available to you after that.

```
code_string = """def f1(p1, p2, p3):
    print("a{}, b{}, c{}".format(p1, p2, p3))
def f2():
    print("text")
"""

code = compile(code_string, '<string>', 'exec')
exec(code)

f1(1, 2, 3)
# a1, b2, c3
f2()
# text
```

Please understand that passing arbitrary code to `exec()` (or *evil* `eval()`) poses a serious security risk.